# Perl : Print Name of Array Passed to sub routine

Tags: arrays, perl

Am passing one array and one scalar to a function to check where that value is part of array or not in case it is not part then push to array. For reference purpose what It has to display is while pushing it has to display the name of array .  Here is my code

```
use v5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ARRAY1 = qw/This is array of backup /;
my @ARRAY2;


my $value = "version.xml" ;


sub CheckPush($$)
{

my $val = shift (@_);
my $array_ref= shift (@_);

     unless ($val ~~ @$array_ref )
     {
        print "$val is going to push to array  \n";
        push(@$array_ref,$val);
     }   
return (@$array_ref);
} 

@ARRAY1 = CheckPush($value,\@ARRAY1);
print "out \n";
foreach $_ (@ARRAY1) {
print "$_ \n";
}

@ARRAY2 = CheckPush ($value,\@ARRAY2);
print "out2 \n";
foreach $_ (@ARRAY2) {
print "$_ \n";
}
```

Out put should be like below

```
$val is going to push Array (@ARRAY1)
$val is going to push Array (@ARRAY2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name of the array along with the reference; it isn't that hard.

People do do things like this with source filters or PadWalker::var_name, but it isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea i was thinking with out passing the array name is there any way to get the name of array

Comment: err, I said how to (at least in limited cases such as the one you show; there is no general purpose answer, which is one of the reasons it isn't a good idea)